# Sphinx: SPH_SORT_EXPR mode - float is not enough

Tags: sphinx

I've noticed that the result of sort expression in SPH_SORT_EXPR mode is float. I'm disappointed because float cannot represent as much data as I want.

I want to achive something like this (in terms of SPH_SORT_EXTENDED mode):

```
@weight DESC attr_a DESC (attr_b - 10000*attr_c) DESC
```

So I tried to represent it in SPH_SORT_EXPR mode as follows:

```
2^33 * @weight + 2^32 * attr_a + attr_b - 10000 * attr_c
```

where `attr_a` is `boolean`, `attr_b` `int` and `attr_c` a tiny int.

However, this approach is not sensitive enough, since the gaps between two consecutive large values that can be represented in float are too big to differentiate sphinx matches (lots of them has the same `@expr` value).

I tried to use `sqrt` but effect is the same.

```
2^17 * floor(sqrt(@weight)) + 2^16 * attr_a + sqrt(attr_b - 10000 * attr_c)
```

Do anyone knows any solutions, workarounds etc.?

I really appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the weight is actually a unsigned 32 bit int. So just the 2^32 cases integer overflow.

Have you tried actually using `SPH_SORT_EXTENDED` ?

```
->setSelect("*, (attr_b - 10000*attr_c) AS sorter");
->setSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@weight DESC, attr_a DESC, sorter DESC");
```

(`SPH_SORT_EXPR` just creates the virtual attribute `@expr` and then sorts it, here you create a virtual `sorter` attribute explicitly)

Comment: I didn't know that `setSelect` exists :) Thanks!